# Class variables in python using Pyglet

Tags: python, class, variables, tuples, pyglet

I'm writing a piece of code for a game I am designing, but I keep running into the same error:

```
import pyglet
class line:
    lines = []
print(line.lines)
def DrawBackground():
    pass
def DrawMidground():
    pyglet.graphics.draw(int(len(lines)/2), pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, ('v2i', tuple(line.lines)))
def DrawForeground():
    pass
config = pyglet.gl.Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4)
window = pyglet.window.Window(config = config, fullscreen = True)
@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    line.lines.append(x)
    line.lines.append(y)
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    DrawBackground()
    DrawMidground()
    DrawForeground()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Raises the exception:

```
      6     pass
      7 def DrawMidground():
----> 8     pyglet.graphics.draw(int(len(lines)/2), pyglet.gl.GL_POLYGON, ('v2i', tuple(line.lines)))
      9 def DrawForeground():
     10     pass

NameError: name 'lines' is not defined
```

I wrote a second program as a test, and it seems to work fine:

```
class line:
    lines = []
def prints():
    print(line.lines)
prints()
```

Returns `[]`

I've tried both renaming the class and the variables, to no avail. Any ideas/tips/solutions? I've been messing with this program for half an hour now and I can't find the problem.

For the first program, the expected result is it opens a window where you can click to add points to make a shape. I'm using the class instead of just 'lines' so that I may add more variables that still use the 'line.' prefix.

Comment: `lines` in `int(len(lines))` is out of scope in that line. In the same line you use `tuple(line.lines)` which would work.

Comment: Is this meant to be one class? In that case would you mind fixing indentation?

Comment: Not, I think not, that's why I deleted my comment, try refreshing :D

Comment: Thank you @LoneLunatic ! I was looking at the tuple function and wondering why it wasn't working XD, I didn't check the rest of the line. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `lines` is not in the global scope because it is a class member of the class `line`. You'd have to use `line.lines` like you do in the rest of your code.